# Android Firebase deeplink not working For redmi xiomi devices

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking

In Redmi device google api client is not able to decode deeplink url to custom url.

This is working for 5.0, below 5.0 it is not working.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mi phone have problem regarding this.When you click on url than open it with google play service, then deeplinking work perfectly.